# Javascript how to insert one array's value to another array according to the matched id?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two javascript arrays which contains different values:

```
var groups = [
    {id: 0, name: "group1", children:[]}, 
    {id: 1, name: "group2",children:[]},
    {id: 2, name: "group3", children:[]},
    {id: 3, name: "group4", children:[]},
    ]
var devices = [
    {id: 0, name:"device1", groupId:0}, 
    {id: 1, name:"device2", groupId:1},
    {id: 2, name:"device3", groupId:1},
    {id: 3, name:"device4", groupId:2},
    ]
```

If the device's groupId equals to the group id, then put it in its children property. Expected result:

```
groupDeviceList = [
    {id: 0, name: "group1", children:[
      {id: 0, name:"device1", groupId:0}, 
    ]}, 
    {id: 1, name: "group2",children:[
      {id: 1, name:"device2", groupId:1},
      {id: 2, name:"device3", groupId:1},
    ]},
    {id: 2, name: "group3", children:[
      {id: 3, name:"device4", groupId:2},
    ]},
    {id: 3, name: "group4", children:[]},
]
```

Comment: And the problem is? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: A loop, + `.filter()` + `.push()` should do the job quite well

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that, could you give an exact code example? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const groups = [
    {id: 0, name: "group1", children:[]}, 
    {id: 1, name: "group2",children:[]},
    {id: 2, name: "group3", children:[]},
    {id: 3, name: "group4", children:[]},
    ];
    
const devices = [
    {id: 0, name:"device1", groupId:0}, 
    {id: 1, name:"device2", groupId:1},
    {id: 2, name:"device3", groupId:1},
    {id: 3, name:"device4", groupId:2},
    ]
    
console.log(groups.map(g => ({...g,children: devices.filter(d => d.groupId === g.id)})));
```

Comment: `.map()` is not the right tool if you're not using its return value (other than for a `console.log()`)

Comment: groups.forEach(g => g.children = devices.filter(d => d.groupId === g.id));